# Want to Access variable by its name with string value in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables

net.  I m trying to access a variable from string value as its name.

I have created a almost 50 variables of class type like A1, A2, A3 as Class type. and also have a list of 50 items in the datatable. what i want is that when access like

```
    dim dr as datarow
    for each dr in dt.rows
    dim newstring as string = dr(0).tostring
    'Here I have the problem, newstring will return A1 or A2 or A3 and I dont want to use if-then or Select case statements becose
it will lead me toward hundreds of lines. I want to access newstring.property=something 

    Next
```

Problem is that the above will return a string value and I have declared a variable the same name as the returned newstring. I want to access only that variable which have the name as newstring. Please help me.

Comment: Was there a good reason for creating them as variables instead of using an associative array (e.g. a hashtable) instead?

Comment: It is actually a seating plan type, but the seat numbers are not in sequence and they all have their properties like isvacant, is reserved etc to access in future. if you suggest any other easy approach, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a class for each seat

```
Private Class Seat
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property IsReserved As Boolean
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
End Class
```

The populate a List with each seat(these can be in whatever order you want)

```
'create your seats
Dim seats As New List(Of Seat)
seats.Add(New Seat("A3"))
seats.Add(New Seat("B6"))
seats.Add(New Seat("A1"))
'etc.
```

Then you can use a linq expression to find a seat that matches the name from your database:

```
'find the seat in the list that matches the name
Dim dr As DataRow
For Each dr In dt.rows
    Dim newstring As String = dr(0).ToString
    Dim seat = seats.Find(Function(x) x.Name = newstring)
    seat.Property = Something
Next
```

Comment: Sir Thank you very much it helps me a lot to solve my problem thanks again.